# Ошибки при создании нескольких таблиц со связями в apex.oracle

Tags: sql, база-данных

Возникают ошибки в `apex.oracle`. Пытаюсь создать базу из 6 таблиц, как видно из кода. Две промежуточные `"Recipe"` и `"DishinYouOrder"`, остальные с одним ключом.

На скриншоте видно ошибки, но не могу разобраться в чём проблема.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```
`create table Ingredients (IDIngredient int not null primary key, nameIN varchar (50) not null, price int not null);

create table Menu (IDDish int primary key, NameDish varchar (50) not null, price int not null, calories int not null, weight int not null);

create table Recipe (
    IDRecipe int not null, 
    IDIngredient int not null references Ingredients (IDIngredient), 
    IDDish int not null references Menu (IDDish));

create table YouOrder (
    IDOrder int not null primary key, IDemployee int not null, Numberofservings int not null, Tablecode int not null, DateOrder date, SumOrder int not null);

create table DishinYouOrder (
    IDDish int not null references Menu (IDDish), 
    IDOrder int not null references YouOrder (IDOrder),
    price int not null,
    Numberofservings int not null);

create table Employee (IDOrder int not null primary key, Tablecode int not null, IDEmployee int not null, FIO varchar (150) not null, phone int not null);
`
```

Надеюсь на вашу помощь! Заранее спасибо!

Comment: Пожалуйста, добавляйте код и тексти ошибки в виде текста, а не в виде картинки. Так его легче читить, по нему можно проводить поиск и копировать.

Comment: Всё нормально создаётся. https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=7645c3cf487726fdece33ae8687aeaa8